# Oracle SQL - best way to use IF NOT EXISTS?

Tags: null, case, exists

I would be most appreciative for help with the following:

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE, A.PHONE AS CELL, B.PHONE AS OFFICE, C.PHONE AS HOME
FROM PHONE_NUMBERS A, PHONE_NUMBERS B, PHONE_NUMBERS C
WHERE A.EMP_NUM = B.EMP_NUM
  AND A.EMP_NUM = C.EMP_NUM
  AND A.PHONE_TYPE = 'CELL'
  AND B.PHONE_TYPE = 'OFFICE'
  AND C.PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME'
```

My issue is the following: if an employee has CELL and HOME phone types, but no entry exists for OFFICE phone type, the query will not return him, because OFFICE does not exist. I have tried CASE statements, but without a phone type, the CASE has nothing to compare. I have read many posts with regard to IF NOT EXISTS, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go. I want the query to return all EMP_NUM, and null if a particular PHONE_TYPE does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Full Outer" joins

```
SELECT coalesce(h.EMPLOYEE, o.EMPLOYEE, c.EMPLOYEE) Employee,
       c.PHONE AS CELL, o.PHONE AS OFFICE, h.PHONE AS HOME
FROM PHONE_NUMBERS h
   full join PHONE_NUMBERS o
      On o.EMP_NUM = h.EMP_NUM 
         and h.PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME'
         and o.PHONE_TYPE = 'OFFICE'
   full join PHONE_NUMBERS C
      On c.EMP_NUM = h.EMP_NUM 
         and c.PHONE_TYPE = 'CELL'
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it's farther along than I was. I'll play with it and comment when I have the whole thing sorted. Thank you.

Comment: Unless you understand already, google on `Full Join` to understand what this is...  If you know what an outer join is , a `full Join` or `Full Outer Join` is a bi-directional outer join, or a join that is "outer" in both directions instead of only left, or right.

Comment: I'm reading about them now, and trying some examples out. I guess my problem lies in the fact that, on my table, it's not that a field is blank. It's that, if it is not populated, the field does not exist. If I have multiple instances of a table (A and B), each occupying field PHONE (A.PHONE and B.PHONE), and those are differentiated by a separate field (PHONE_TYPE), how do I generate NULL for a PHONE_TYPE that does not exist for an employee? It's not blank, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try OUTER JOIN.
This is an example for OUTER JOIN with (+)

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE, A.PHONE AS CELL, B.PHONE AS OFFICE, C.PHONE AS HOME
FROM PHONE_NUMBERS A, PHONE_NUMBERS B, PHONE_NUMBERS C
WHERE A.EMP_NUM = B.EMP_NUM
AND A.EMP_NUM = C.EMP_NUM
AND A.PHONE_TYPE = 'CELL' (+)
AND B.PHONE_TYPE = 'OFFICE' (+)
AND C.PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME' (+)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that (+) doesn't work across the board. I'm querying Oracle (PeopleSoft). I'm getting an error.